# Ambiguous Call - Templated Function

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to brush up on my C++ knowledge and found this issue I cannot Google for easily.

I've written a function with the following signature:

```cpp
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator lower_bound(
    Iterator left,
    Iterator right,
    typename Iterator::value_type const& target
) {
    //stuff happens here
}
```

and I'm trying to use it like so:

```cpp
std::vector<int> odd{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int i = 4;
std::cout << std::distance(odd.begin(), lower_bound(odd.begin(), odd.end(), i)) << std::endl;
```

I'm getting the following compilation error: `error: call to 'lower_bound' is ambiguous`.

I'm guessing I'm lacking some understanding about how template types are resolved and so would be grateful for any resources that might explain this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `std::lower_bound` is causing the ambiguity. Due to [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) your function as well as the std version are around.

If you use your own (non-`std`) iterator type, then you would not face any problem. See the example below ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wv-7gC)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct myIter {
    using value_type = T;
    myIter(T* const ptr) : ptr(ptr) {};
    T& operator*() {return *ptr;};
    T* ptr;
};

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator lower_bound(
    Iterator left,
    Iterator right,
    typename Iterator::value_type const& target) 
{
    return left;
}

int main()
{
std::vector<int> odd{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
myIter<int> b(&(odd.front())), e(&(odd.back()));

int i = 4;
std::cout << *(lower_bound(b,e, i)) << std::endl; // <- works
// std::cout << *(lower_bound(odd.begin(),odd.end(), i)) << std::endl; // <- compiler error
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would not have thought of that.

Just to state here for posterity nesting my `lower_bound` method in a namespace would have also averted this problem.

Comment: Yes, using a namespace would also be perfectly fine.